# Code coverage of java code tested by groovy code

Tags: java, groovy, code-coverage, sonarqube, jacoco

I've a small project where the main code is wrote in java but the tests are mostly groovy code. If i use JaCoCo for code coverage (called by Sonar), the code coverage is not done on my java code, as it seems JaCoCo does not use its special classloader when loading the java classes with groovy. Strangely, I remember it worked before (before sonar version 2.12 which embed JaCoCo).

Does anyone know how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake: forgot to add the integration-test maven profile to the sonar configuration in jenkins.